# Eigenvalues of an integral operator

Tags: operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, spectral-theory, compact-operators, unbounded-operators

The following operator is defined on $L_2(0,1)$:
$$Kf(t)=\int_0^1|s-t|f(s)ds$$

I am wondering how I can calculate the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of such an operator. I start with $\int_0^1|s-t|f(s)ds=\lambda f(t)$ and I took the derivative of both side twice then I got:
$$2f(t)=\lambda f''(t)$$
However, I don't know what boundary condition I should apply to $f(t)$. I would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Are you working with real or complex functions?

Comment: Working with real funtions

Comment: Good, this is my assumption in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

You have two cases.

The first one is $\lambda = 0$ which implies $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in (0,1)$. Hence $\lambda = 0$ is not a eigenvalue.

The second one is $\lambda \neq 0$. In that case, $f$ has to satisfy the differential equation $$f^{\prime \prime}(t)-\frac{2}{\lambda}f(t)=0 \tag{2}$$ If $\lambda < 0$, you can write $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{2}{-\lambda}}$ and the solutions of $(2)$ are $$f(t)=A \cos (\omega t +\varphi), (A,\varphi) \in \mathbb R^2$$ Now you can plug those solutions into the definition of the operator $K$ to find the values of $\omega, \varphi$. If my intermediate computations are correct, you'll find $$\begin{cases}
\varphi = - \omega\\
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2}{-\lambda}} \in \{2 k \pi + \pi : k \ge 0\}
\end{cases}$$ Which provides the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for $\lambda < 0$.

Finally, you have to consider the case $\lambda >0$ which can be solved in a similar way using hyperbolic trigonometry.

Comment: Can we make an analysis on $\lambda$ to find that whether it is positive or negative without trying it into the equation?

Comment: I haven't made the computation for $\lambda > 0$, there might also be positive eigenvalues. I don't see a way to make a qualitative analysis.

Comment: Since $K$ is a compact operator, is this contradicts with the infinitely many countable eigenvalues you just obtained?

Comment: No. If you read my answer in details, I found a countable infinite number of eigenvalues. And I let you look at the case $\lambda > 0$.